# Spatial Index for a geography column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, spatial-query, spatial-index

In a table with almost 50 million rows, there's a `geography` column.

I've already created a spatial index on that column and when I tried to execute the below query

```sql
SELECT
    table_name.column_name.STDistance(geography::STPointFromText (('POINT(latidude longitude)'), 4326)) AS dist
FROM       
    table_name (nolock)
INNER JOIN 
    table_name_2 (nolock) ON (some conditions)
INNER JOIN 
    table_name_3 (nolock) ON (some conditions)
WHERE   
    geography::STPolyFromText (('POLYGON((latitude longitude))'), 4326).STContains(table_name.column_name) = 1
```

This query is running for a very long time.

Apart from the spatial index, is there something else I can do to improve the performance of this query?

Comment: Why are you spamming your `NOLOCK` hint here? Do you "need" to use it? If you "must" use it, why are you using deprecated syntax or not just changing the isolation level of your query, as you're using it against *every* table? [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: You'll notice that for *geography*, [`STContains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16#geography) isn't in the list of methods supported by spatial indexes. So why would you expect it to benefit from one?